# Алгоритмы распознаваня изображений

Tags: data-structures, распознавание

Даны алгоритм по распознаванию образов, которые нужно реализовать - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxxxoAIFa58na1J3Q1pTV1NFRjQ/edit

Проблема в том, что информации по этим алгоритмам в практически нету. Предполагаю, что они просто называются по-другому.

Подскажите, что за алгоритмы и в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Что Вам непонятно в этом алгоритме? Отдалённо напоминает метод k-средних. Можно посмотреть в сторону перцептрона Розенблатта.

Comment: [Здесь много полезной инфы](https://habr.com/ru/post/414425/):)))

Answer (score 1):

Здесь представлены варианты алгоритма  ISODATA. Когда изначально задаётся количество классов. Также некоторые алгоритмы возможно k-средних. Алгоритм СПЕКТР похож на алгоритм перегруппировки после кластеризации с использованием функционалов качества
(дисперсионно-ковариационных критериев)